# Rank of a linear combination of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a set of quadratic forms $Q_i (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$ in $n$ variables, defined over $\mathbb{R}$.  We suppose these are 'collectively nondegenerate' in the sense that there does not exist a change of variables which takes us into a set of quadratic forms with less than $n$ variables.

I am looking at linear combinations of these forms: $$ Q_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}}(\textbf{x})=\sum_i \lambda_i Q_i(x_1, \dots, x_n)$$ for $\boldsymbol{\lambda} = (\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k$.  My question is whether we are guaranteed a set of $\lambda$s which gives us a quadratic form of full rank i.e. $n$?  **Edit:**: this has been shown to be untrue, so...

Is there anything we can do to guarantee a 'high' rank, say bigger than 5?  For example by taking $n \gg k$?

Comment: In matrixspeak: Given $k$ square matrices whose kernels have trivial intersection, can we find a nonsingular matrices which can be written as a linear combination of our $k$ matrices?

Comment: The answer to this is no. Take for instance the elementary matrices $E_{1j}$ for $1 \le j \le n$. 

Comment: Could you please show what happens with only 2 variables? Your command boldsymbol does not work for me, I am still using jsMath, but you might switch to \bf or leave it out...

Comment: Keivan, the matrices would  be symmetric.

Comment: Will: I agree and I don't know how to do it for symmetric matrices. My comment was in refernce to darji's comment, basically saying that the extra assumption is needed.

Comment: Will: If you symmetrize Keivan's counterexample (replace $E_{1j}$ with $E_{1j}+E_{j1}$) you get a symmetric counterexample.

Comment: Noah: I don't think so: think of the forms $x_1x_2$ and $x_3x_4$ whose sum is non-degenerate.

Comment: Keivan, I see, "Darij, your formulation does not quite capture the problem." $$ $$ As always, I would like for the OP to show what happens in 2 by 2 and perhaps 3 by 3. 

Comment: I don't understand the problem with Noah's comment.

It would seem to me that $x_1^2, x_1 x_2 , \dots , x_1 x_n$ are a counterexample to my original question since:

$x_1^2 + 2\lambda_2 x_1 x_2 + \dots 2\lambda_n x_1 x_n$ equals $(x_1+ \lambda_2 x_2 + \lambda_n x_n^2)^2 - (\lambda_2 x_2 + \lambda_n x_n^2)^2$ so this will always have rank 2

The 2nd part of my question - what if we take $k \ll n ?$

Comment: Can't you get a $n=3\nu$, $k=2$ example from Dustin's $n=3$, $k=2$ example by copypasting his matrices as diagonal blocks?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I should be more clear: I'm not expecting to be able to get full rank anymore. For my purposes all I actually need is rank 5. Will edit OP.

How about something like this: we only need one of our original forms to be of rank 5 and we will be done, if $n \geq 5k$ then either one of the forms must be of rank $\geq5$ or the dimension of the intersection of the nullspaces will be greater than 0 ?

Comment: Uhm... If $n\geq 5k$ and all forms are of rank $< 5$, then the codimension of the kernel of each form is $< 5$ (since the codimension of the kernel of a linear map is always equal to the rank), which means the same as $\leq 4$, and thus the codimension of the kernel of their sum is $\leq 4k$ which is quite a lot smaller than $5k=n$. So the kernel at least has dimension $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first part (about finding a linear combination which has full rank) is no. A counterexample with $n=3$ and $k=2$ is given by the quadratic forms $xy$ and $xz$. A general linear combination of these two is of the form $\lambda_1 xy + \lambda_2 xz = x(\lambda_1 y + \lambda_2 z)$, which obviously has rank 2.

The equivalent formulation in terms of symmetric matrices is that any linear combination of
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}
is singular, but if we put the matrices side by side, then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
has full rank.